# Is it possible to create a "bootstrapped" interpreter independent of the original interpreter?

Tags: language-agnostic, compiler, interpreters

According to [Wikipedia, the term "bootstrapping" in the context of writing compilers means this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bootstrapping_(compilers)):

> In computer science, bootstrapping is the process of writing a compiler (or assembler) in the source programming language that it intends to compile. Applying this technique leads to a self-hosting compiler.

And I can understand how that would work. However, the story seems to be a little different for interpreters. Now, of course, it is possible to write a self-hosting interpreter. That's not what I'm asking. What I'm actually asking is: **Is it possible to make a self-hosted interpreter independent of the original, first interpreter**. To explain what I mean, consider this example:

You write your first interpreter version in language **X**, and the interpreter is for a new language you're creating, called **Y**. You first use language **X**'s compiler to create an executable. You now can interpret files written in your new language **Y** using the interpreter written in language **X**.

Now, as far as I understand, to be able to "bootstrap" the interpreter you wrote in language **X**, you'd need to rewrite the interpreter in language **Y**. But here is the catch: even if you do rewrite the entire interpreter in language **Y**, you're still going to need the original interpreter you wrote in language **X**. Because to run the interpreter in language **Y**, you're going to have to interpret the source files. But what exactly is going to interpret the source files? Well, it can't be nothing, of course, so you're forced to still use the first interpreter.

No matter how many new interpreters you write in language **Y**, you're always going to have to use the first interpreter written in **X** to interpret the subsequent interpreters. This seems to be a problem simply because of the nature of interpreters.

*However*, on the flip side, [This Wikipedia article on interpreters actually talks about self-hosting interpreters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interpreter_(computing)#Self-interpreter). Here is a small excerpt which is relevant:

> A self-interpreter is a programming language interpreter written in a programming language which can interpret itself; an example is a BASIC interpreter written in BASIC. Self-interpreters are related to self-hosting compilers.
>
> If no compiler exists for the language to be interpreted, creating a self-interpreter requires the implementation of the language in a host language (which may be another programming language or assembler). By having a first interpreter such as this, the system is bootstrapped and new versions of the interpreter can be developed in the language itself

It's still not clear to me though, how exactly this would be done. It seems that no matter what, you're always going to be forced to use the first version of your interpreter written in the host language.

Now the article mentioned above [links to another article in which Wikipedia gives some examples of supposed self-hosting interpreters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meta-circular_evaluator#Examples). Upon closer inspection though, it seems that the main "interpreting" part of many of those self-hosting interpreters (especially some of the more common ones such as PyPy or Rubinius) are actually written in other languages such as C++ or C.

So is what I describe above possible? Can a self-hosted interpreter be independent of its original host? If so, how exactly would this be done?

Comment: To add a fresh breadcrumb to a stale question: The formal approach to this is known as "Futamura projections", drawing a sharp line between compilers and interpreters. In the paper "Is there a fourth Futamura projection?" it is shown that the fourth Futamura projection does not create a new type of compiler, but instead changes the compiled language; repeated applications of this projection create a bootstrapping effect.

Comment: Thanks, @Corbin, sounds interesting! I'll to look into more whenever I get a break...

Answer (score 25, accepted):

The short answer is: you are right in your suspicion, you always need either another interpreter written in **X** or a compiler from **Y** to some other language for which you have an interpreter already. Interpreters execute, compilers only translate from one language to another, at *some* point in your system, there *must* be an interpreter … even it's just the CPU.

> No matter how many new interpreters you write in language **Y**, you're always going to have to use the first interpreter written in **X** to interpret the subsequent interpreters. This seems to be a problem simply because of the nature of interpreters.

Correct. What you *can* do is write a compiler from **Y** to **X** (or another language for which you have an interpreter), and you can even do that in **Y**. Then you can run your **Y** compiler written in **Y** on the **Y** interpreter written in **X** (or on the **Y** interpreter written in **Y** running on the **Y** interpreter written in **X**, or on the **Y** interpreter written in **Y** running on the **Y** interpreter written in **Y** running on the **Y** interpreter written in **X**, or … ad infinitum) to compile your **Y** interpreter written in **Y** to **X**, so that you can then execute it on an **X** interpreter. That way, you have gotten rid of your **Y** interpreter written in **X**, but now you need the **X** interpreter (we know that we already have one, though, since otherwise we couldn't ran the **X** interpreter written in **Y**), *and* you had to write a **Y**-to-**X**-compiler first.

> *However*, on the flip side, The Wikipedia article on interpreters actually talks about self-hosting interpreters. Here is a small excerpt which is relevant:
>
> > A self-interpreter is a programming language interpreter written in a programming language which can interpret itself; an example is a BASIC interpreter written in BASIC. Self-interpreters are related to self-hosting compilers.
> >
> > If no compiler exists for the language to be interpreted, creating a self-interpreter requires the implementation of the language in a host language (which may be another programming language or assembler). By having a first interpreter such as this, the system is bootstrapped and new versions of the interpreter can be developed in the language itself
>
> It's still not clear to me though, how exactly this would be done. It seems that no matter what, you're always going to be forced to use the first version of your interpreter written in the host language.

Correct. Note that the Wikipedia article explicitly says that you need a *second* implementation of your language, and it doesn't say that you can get rid of the first.

> Now the article mentioned above links to another article in which Wikipedia gives some examples of supposed self-hosting interpreters. Upon closer inspection though, it seems that the main "interpreting" part of many of those self-hosting interpreters (especially some of the more common ones such as PyPy or Rubinius) are actually written in other languages such as C++ or C.

Again, correct. Those are really bad examples. Take Rubinius, for example. Yes, it's true that the Ruby part of Rubinius is self-hosted, but it is a compiler, not an interpreter: it compiles to Ruby source code to Rubinius bytecode. The interpreter part OTOH isn't self-hosted: it interprets Rubinius bytecode, but it is written in C++. So, calling Rubinius a "self-hosted interpreter" is wrong: the *self-hosted* part isn't an *interpreter*, and the *interpreter* part isn't *self-hosted*.

PyPy is similar, but even more incorrect: it isn't even written in Python in the first place, it is written in RPython, which is a different language. It is syntactically similar to Python, semantically an "extended subset", but it actually is a statically-typed language roughly on the same abstraction level as Java, and its implementation is a compiler with multiple backends which compiles RPython to C source code, ECMAScript source code, CIL byte code, JVM bytecode, or Python sourcecode.

> So is what I describe above possible? Can a self-host interpreter be independent of its original host? If so, how exactly would this be done?

No, not on its own. You would either need to keep the original interpreter or write a compiler and compile your self-interpreter.

There *are* some meta-circular VMs, such as [Klein](https://github.com/AdamSpitz/klein) (written in [Self](http://www.selflanguage.org/)) and [Maxine](https://labs.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=labs:49:::::P49_PROJECT_ID:9) (written in Java). Note, however, that here the definition of "meta-circular" is yet different: these VMs are not *written* in the language they execute: Klein executes Self bytecode but is written in Self, Maxine executes JVM bytecode but is written in Java. However, the Self / Java source code of the VM actually gets compiled to Self / JVM bytecode and then executed by the VM, so by the time the VM gets executed, it *is* in the language it executes. Phew.

Note also that this is different from VMs such as the [SqueakVM](http://squeak.org/) and the [Jikes RVM](http://jikesrvm.org/). Jikes is written in Java, and the SqueakVM is written in Slang (a statically typed syntactic and semantic subset of Smalltalk roughly on the same abstraction level as a high-level assembler), and both get statically compiled to native code before they are run. They don't run inside of themselves. You *can*, however, run them *on-top of themselves* (or on top of another Smalltalk VM / JVM). But that is not "meta-circular" in this sense.

Maxine and Klein, OTOH *do* run inside of themselves; they execute their own bytecode using their own implementation. This is truly mindbending! It allows some cool optimization opportunities, for example since the VM executes itself together with the user program, it can inline calls from the user program to the VM and vice versa, e.g. call to the garbage collector or the memory allocator can be inlined into user code, and reflective callbacks in the user code can be inlined into the VM. Also, all of the clever optimization tricks that modern VMs do, where they watch the executing program and optimize it depending on the actual workload and data, the VM can apply those same tricks to itself while it is executing the user program while the user program is executing the specific workload. In other words, the VM highly specialized itself for *that* particular program running *that* particular workload.

However, notice I skirted around the use of the word "interpreter" above, and always used "execute"? Well, those VMs aren't built around interpreters, they are built around (JIT) compilers. There was an interpreter added to Maxine later, but you always need the compiler: you have to run the VM *once* on top of another VM (e.g. Oracle HotSpot in the case of Maxine), so that the VM can (JIT) compile itself. In the case of Maxine, it will JIT compile its own bootup phase, then serialize that compiled native code to a bootstrap VM image and stick a very simple bootloader in front (the only component of the VM written in C, although that's just for convenience, it could be in Java also). Now you can use Maxine to execute itself.

Comment: _Yeesh_. I never knew the world of self-hosting interpreters was so sticky! Thanks for giving a nice overview though.

Comment: Haha, well, why should the world be less mind-bending than the concept? ;-)

Comment: I guess one of the problems is that people often play fast and loose with the languages involved. For example, Rubinius is usually called "Ruby in Ruby", but that's only half the story. Yes, *strictly speaking*, the Ruby compiler in Rubinius is written in Ruby, but the VM which executes the bytecode is not. And even worse: PyPy is often called "Python in Python", except there's actually not a single line of Python in there. The whole thing is written in RPython, which is designed to be familiar to Python programmers, but *is not Python*. Likewise SqueakVM: it is not written in Smalltalk, it …

Comment: … is written in Slang, which according to people who have actually coded in it, is even worse than C in its abstraction capabilities. The only advantage Slang has, is that it is a proper subset of Smalltalk which means that you can develop it (and run and most importantly debug the VM on) a powerful Smalltalk IDE.

Comment: Well thanks for clarifying that. For the longest time I've always heard people talk about how PyPy is directly written in Python. Now maybe this post can help demystify things ;-)

Comment: The PyPy authors describe RPython roughly "Syntax and semantics of Python, speed of C, restrictions of Java and compiler error messages as penetrable as MUMPS". (Note: MUMPS is renowned for being hard to understand.)

Comment: Well what do you expect from a language named _MUMPS_! ;) Anyways, I'll stop bugging. The site seems to think my comment are no longer "constructive". Thanks again.

Comment: Just to add another complication: Some interpreted languages (e.g. FORTH, and possibly TeX) are capable of writing a loadable memory image of the running system, as an executable file. In that sense, such systems *can* then run without the original interpreter. For example I once wrote a FORTH interpreter by using an 16-bit version of FORTH to "cross-interpret" a 32-bit version for a different CPU, and to run on a different OS. (Note, the FORTH language includes its own assembler, so the "FORTH VM" (which is typically only 10 or 20 machine code instructions) can be written in FORTH itself.)

Comment: PyPy *is* written in Python, as evidenced from the fact you can bootstrap it from CPython. It's just that it's *also* largely implemented in RPython. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/8569919/1763356.

Comment: @Veedrac Well yes, technically, I guess that is the case. However, it seems to me that the actual interesting part of PyPy - the "interpretering" part - is not written in Python.

Comment: @ChristianDean RPython code is Python code, so it is written in Python.

Comment: @Veedrac No. RPython is not Python. RPython is a restricted subset of Python. They are related, but they are not the same. They are two distinct languages, each with a different purpose.

Comment: @ChristianDean That RPython is not Python does not stop RPython code from being Python code. If it runs in a Python VM, it's Python.

Comment: @Veedrac Alright, I think I understand where you're coming from.

Answer (score 7):

You are correct in noting that a self-hosting interpreter still requires an interpreter to run itself, and can't be bootstrapped in the same sense as a compiler.

However, a self-hosted *language* is not the same thing as a self-hosted interpreter. It is usually easier to build an interpreter than it is to build a compiler. Therefore, to implement a new language, we might first implement an interpreter in an unrelated language. Then we can use that interpreter to develop a compiler for our language. The language is then self-hosted, since the compiler is interpreted. The compiler can then compile itself, and can then be considered fully bootstrapped.

A special case of this is a self-hosting JIT-compiling runtime. It can start with an interpreter in a host language, which then uses the new language to implement JIT-compilation, after which the JIT-compiler can compile itself. This feels like a self-hosting interpreter, but sidesteps the infinite-interpreters problem. This approach is used, but is not yet very common.

Another related technique is an extensible interpreter, where we can create extensions in the language being interpreted. For example, we might implement new opcodes in the language. This can turn a bare-bones interpreter into a feature-rich interpreter, as long as we avoid circular dependencies.

A case that actually occurs fairly commonly is the ability of the language to influence its own parsing, e.g. as parse-time evaluated macros. Since the macro language is the same as the language being processed, it tends to be far more feature-rich than dedicated or restricted macro languages. However, it is correct to note that the language performing the extension is a slightly different language than the language after extension.

When “real” self-hosted interpreters are used, this is usually done for reasons of education or research. E.g. implementing an interpreter for Scheme inside Scheme is a cool way to teach programming languages (see SICP).